# How to extract frustum planes from Ortho matrix?

Tags: opengl, orthographic, frustum

I have extracted the frustum planes from a perspective matrix with some help from [this homepage](http://www.txutxi.com/?p=444).

Can I use the same equations for an orthographic matrix?

************************UPDATED************************

I'm using cascaded shadow mapping(CSM) with 4 cascades and need therefore cull objects in different cascades from the lights perspective. It would be quite expensive to calculate the 6 frustum planes with this method:

Fore each cascade:

1. Calculate the inverse matrix from the finalMatrix = lightOrthoMatrix * lightViewMatrix.
2. Use the inverse final matrix and multiply it with the 8 frustum NDC corners to get the final frustum corners in world space.
3. Use these corners to finally calculate the 6 frustum planes.

I discovered today that you can use the same "cheap" method to calculate the 6 frustum planes by extracting them from the final matrix. See [this homepage](http://ruh.li/CameraViewFrustum.html). It doesn't matter if we use Perspective Projection or Orthographic Projection.

Comment: both links are dead